# pandas adding 0 when adding =HYPERLINK to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add hyperlink to a column, but if the column is empty it adding `0` to it

```
def hyperlink(row):
  return f'=HYPERLINK("{row.link}", "{row.a}")' if row.a else ''

df["a"] = df.apply(hyperlink, axis=1)

df.drop(columns=["link"], inplace=True)

with pd.ExcelWriter(engine="xlsxwriter") as writer:
   df.to_excel(writer)

   wb = writer.book
   ws = wb.sheets["sheet1"]

   text_format = wb.add_format({
            "font_name": "Calibri",
            "font_size": "11",
            "bold": False,
            "valign": "vcenter",
            "font_color": "blue",
    })
   text_format.set_num_format("@")
   ws.set_column("A:A", 24, text_format)
```

Note: "link" is column in df.
I am also adding text format to this "a" column.

So if column "a" is empty it should return blank string (''), but somehow when doing to_excel it is adding 0 to value, and hence breaking excel sheet.

Please guide what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might occur because of how excel handles different types of data. You can try returning None instead of '', that way it should leave the row empty the way you wish

```
def hyperlink(row):
if row.a:
    return f'=HYPERLINK("{row.link}", "{row.a}")'
else:
    return None
```

Comment: Tried this, but not working. it is still adding '0' to empty value.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by avoiding usage of `=HYPERLINK()` formula in dataframe. Hyperlink formula is adding 0 when data is not there for any row.
Instead, I did the below:

```
def link_text(row):
  link = ""
  if row.a
    link = f"{row.link},{row.a}"
  return link

df["a"] = df.apply(link_text, axis=1)

df.drop(columns=["link"], inplace=True)

with pd.ExcelWriter(engine="xlsxwriter", engine_kwargs={"options": {"strings_to_urls": False}},) as writer:
   df.to_excel(writer)

   wb = writer.book
   ws = wb.sheets["sheet1"]

   text_format = wb.add_format({
            "font_name": "Calibri",
            "font_size": "11",
            "bold": False,
            "valign": "vcenter",
            "font_color": "blue",
    })
   text_format.set_num_format("@")
   ws.set_column("A:A", 24, text_format)

   for row_no, value in enumerate(df["a").to_list()):
     worksheet.write_url(
        row=row_no,
        col=0,
        string=value.split(",")[0],
        url=value.split(",")[1],
        cell_format=text_format
     )
```